# Compactness of modal logic by proving existence of a model for a maximal set (using Zorn's lemma)

Tags: proof-writing, compactness, order-theory, model-theory, modal-logic

TASK: Given a set $\Gamma$ of propositional modal formulas where every finite subset of $\Gamma$ is satisfiable (say: $\Gamma$ is finitely satisfiable), show that $\Gamma$ itself is satisfiable.

IDEA: For propositional logic, a common proof is to build a set $\Omega$ of each superset $\Psi\supseteq\Gamma$, such that $\Psi$ is finitely satisfiable, and show that the partial order $(\Omega,\subseteq)$ contains a maximal element $\Phi_{max}\in\Omega$, which follows from Zorn's lemma, since every chain $C$ in $(\Omega,\subseteq)$ has an upper bound $\bigcup C$ in $(\Omega,\subseteq)$.
Then one can show that when exactly those propositions that hold true by a model $\mathfrak{I}$ are contained in $\Phi_{max}$, it follows that exactly all formulas that hold true by $\mathfrak{I}$ are contained in $\Phi_{max}$ (by structural induction). Consequently, $\mathfrak{I}$ is a model for $\Phi_{max}$, therefore it is a model for $\Gamma\subseteq\Phi_{max}$, thus $\Gamma$ is satisfiable.

ATTEMPT: I wonder how one can use this idea and extend it to a modal logic with multiple worlds, i.e. multiple interpretations $(\mathfrak{I}^w)_{w\in\mathfrak{W}}$ make a model. It is apparently not suffient to build $\Phi_{max}$ only once, as a formula $\Box\psi$ depends on all interpretations, but a set $\Gamma$ of modal formulas is satisfiable if and only if there is some world $w\in\mathfrak{W}$ such that $\Gamma$ is satisfiable in $w$. (So we cannot argue for $(\mathfrak{I}^w)_{w\in\mathfrak{W}},w\vDash\Box\psi$ iff $\Box\psi\in\Phi_{max}$, since required information is hidden from $\Phi_{max}$.)

My first idea was to consider sets in $ML\times\mathfrak{W}$, so for a maximal set it can be argued whether it contains $(\Box\psi,w)$, by testing if it contains $(\psi,w')$ for all $w'\in\mathfrak{W}$. But I fail to build such a maximal set $\Phi_{max}\subseteq ML\times\mathfrak{W}$ with the property of finite satisfiability containing supersets of the given $\Gamma\subseteq ML$.

Are you aware of a compactness proof for modal logics following this idea, or do you have an idea for a construction of $\Omega$ on which Zorn's lemma can be applied, such that a model for $\Phi_{max}$ can be constructed to imply satisfiability of $\Gamma$?

(I prefer this approach over using a standard translation, because the modal logic I consider is very hard to axiomatize in first-order logic (e.g. it requires all ZFC axioms to be part of a translation for a certain operator to state required set-theoretic properties). But it is only propositional and extends $S5$. Can it really be so hard to show compactness?)

Comment: There is a completeness theorem to that appears in Hajek's classic text: The metamathematics of Fuzzy logic. It is the closest thing what I can think of to what you are asking. Maybe taking a look won't hurt?

Comment: @dav11 There are many completeness theorems in that book, most with an external (cited) proof. What completeness theorem do you mean (or in which chapter), and why is its proof close to this compactness proof idea?

Comment: There is one proved within the book for a countable language, a little futher on. It uses the same things you have listed under "idea". I'm only claiming that it may be related as I'm unsure about what you want to do, but it, as I mentioned is the closest thing I can think of that you may be able to modify.

Comment: Note that I want to use Zorn's lemma to be able to prove compactness even for uncountably many propositions. The things listed under "IDEA" are pretty clear to work, the idea is taken from the script of my mathematical logics course where it was used to prove compactness of propositional logic. The only thing I wonder how it works it how to extend this idea to multiple worlds. So what does fuzzy logics have to do with multiple worlds? I do not see the connection. Also, I do not find the proof that you mean.